# Cycling through RGB colors in hex

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I am creating a color picker type tool using a table. I want to apply a color to each cell in 16 by 16 table. I am having trouble with cycling through colors probably because I'm not sure how to go about it. How should I do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "cycling through colors"? Have you made any attempt at this at all? If not, you should, and then come back with a more specific, less open-ended question.

Comment: There are far more than 256 hex color values, and a 16-by-16 grid can only include 256 colors. You'll need to decide which specific colors you want.

Comment: Maybe this can be a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/ar3q406k/1/

Answer (score 0):

#### Hexagonal

You can use this [BaseConverter](https://gist.github.com/faisalman/4213592). Make a loops that writes decimal numbers in 0-255 range with given interval, converts them to hexagonal and create a string containing hex number of three colors with a "#" before them (rgb).

It will work the same way as snippet below but you need to convert numbers additionaly: `"rgb(" + (i * interval) + ", " + (j * interval) + ", " + (k * interval) + ")"` will be changed to `"#" + bin2hex(i * interval) + bin2hex(j * interval) + bin2hex(k * interval)`.

#### Decimal with an example

Otherwise just use the other format of [CSS Colors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) which is `rgb(red, green, blue)` which takes decimal numbers as arguments.

```js
/* Please keep in mind that this function is just an example.
   You can modify it to create different palette schemes. */
var tot = 800; /* total amount of blocks */
var num = Math.pow(tot, 1/3); /* amount of blocks in one axis */
var interval = parseInt(255 / num); /* color diff step */
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
var tmp = 0;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < num; j++) { 
       for (k = 0; k < num; k++) {
           /* creates block, add styled class and set color */
           var block = document.createElement("div");
           block.className = "foo";
           block.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + (i * interval) + ", " + (j * interval) + ", " + (k * interval) + ")";
           cont.appendChild(block);
           /* i - red, j - green, k - blue */
           tmp++;
       }
    }
}
```

```css
.foo {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- It will be populated with JS -->
<div id="container"></div>
```

If I get the idea of your question wrong then sorry. That's how I would understand "cycle".

The problem you might encounter is that `rgb()` takes three arguments and you want to create two dimensional array with it. Try looking for `rgb palette` in google graphics to get the idea how RGB palette may look like and then change the code from above.